# SSH tunnelling with multiple dynamic port forwardings

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I am trying to monitor multiple JVMs running on different servers through an ssh tunnel.

Thanks to one of the UNIX gurus here, I have managed to get this running for a single server by:

1. Run `jstatd` on the target server
2. Set up Visual VM to use 9696 as its socks proxy port.
3. On my local PC, run:

   ```
   ssh -L 2222:server1:22 bastion-host
   ```
4. On my local PC, run:

   ```
   ssh -o port=2222 -D 9696 -L 1099:localhost:1099 localhost
   ```

This does the trick. Now when I try and tunnel to a second server I try:

1. On my local PC, run:

   ```
   ssh -L 3333:server2:22 bastion-host
   ```
2. On my local PC, run:

   ```
   ssh -o port=3333 -D 9696 -L 2099:localhost:1099 localhost
   ```

However, the last step complains with:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 9696
```

Has anyone managed to do something similar?

**Update:**

The reason this is so complex is that jstatd is an RMI server application:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstatd.html

As with RMI applications, these register with an rmiregistry. Using rmi through a firewall requires me to use SOCKS as described here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/faq.html#firewallOut

Unfortunately, visualvm only lets me set the SOCKS proxy port once, and the -D option won't allow me to forward the same local port to both servers...

Comment: You don't need the two sets of tunnels you have - you can ssh to one machine and tunnel out of it into another machine.  Answer updated to include that.

Comment: What's the point of redirecting ports `1099`? Could you precise whether `bastion-host` can connect to `server1` and `server2` without a firewall being involved?

Comment: Have you tried using the most simple option, at the bottom of my answer, and if so, what error / problem did it give?

Comment: @EightBitTony - Unfortunately this wont work, since rmi opens a random port once connection is established. The purpose of the -D option is to tell the rmi server what port it should use. However, I can only specify the SOCKS proxy port once in visualvm, and my 2 tunnels cannot share the -D option.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706685/java-rmi-client-side-random-ports

Comment: The document linked to suggests a SOCKS server is a perfectly valid option, a straight -D is a socks server, so I still don't understand why it doesn't work.  When you say 'it won't work' have you tried it at any stage?  ssh -D 9000 user@bastion-host and then connect to your own localhost as a socks server on port 9000.

Comment: @EightButTony. Yes. Yes I have. As I say, it works absolutely fine for establishing a connection to jstatd running on server1. But I do not appear to be able to set up the second connection to server2, since it complains about the SOCKS proxy port already being used.

Comment: What complains about the SOCKS port?  Visual VM? or another SSH command?

Comment: @toolkit let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1180/discussion-between-eightbittony-and-toolkit)

Answer (score 5):

Am I right in thinking you've got your computer (computer A), and say two servers (A and B) which you can't connect to directly on a certain port and so want to tunnel to them over SSH?

If so, you create two tunnels from your machine (one to each target server) on different local ports using -L not -D, and then in your monitoring tool you connect to your local machine (no proxy settings) as if it was the remote server you want to check.

```
ssh -L 9000:localhost:<local port jstatd listens on> user@server1
ssh -L 9001:localhost:<local port jstatd listens on> user@server2
```

Then using your local monitor you connect to localhost:9000 and localhost:9001 and those tunnels connect you to your target jstatd's.

If there's an intermediate server, then a two hop tunnel,

```
ssh -L 9000:server1:<local port jstatd listens on> user@bastion-host
ssh -L 9001:server2:<local port jstatd listens on> user@bastion-host
```

Hmm, if bastion-host can talk to all the JVM's, then

```
ssh -D 9000 user@bastion-host
```

Is enough to create a socks proxy you can then just use over port 9000.

Comment: This answer looks helpful, I was about to write something similar, could the downvoter give some reason?

Answer (score 3):

From the ssh manpage:

```
 -D [bind_address:]port
         Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port forwarding.
         This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local
         side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a
         connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
         the secure channel, and the application protocol is then used to
         determine where to connect to from the remote machine.  Currently
         the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are supported, and ssh will act
         as a SOCKS server.  Only root can forward privileged ports.
         Dynamic port forwardings can also be specified in the configura‐
         tion file.
```

You're specifying the same local port to forward from twice; Try `-D 9697` on your second setup.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that visualvm only lets me set this once. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Use -L, not -D, as specified in @EightBitTony's answer.  -D is for SOCKS-style proxing - eg, routing HTTP through an SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

The last step says enough: It can't start listening at port 9696. That's because if it's your second tunnel you should use another port while 9696 is handling the first one.